# get array of TextViews

Tags: android, android-view

I'm making an app that stores results in a multiple textviews,
First, I need to get the views, they are 20 views named result 1, .... result 20.
how can i get them to an array of textview.
I found this method but it's too long

```
TextView [] results = {(TextView)findViewById (R.id.result1),
            (TextView)findViewById (R.id.result2),(TextView)findViewById (R.id.result3),
            (TextView)findViewById (R.id.result4),(TextView)findViewById (R.id.result5),
            (TextView)findViewById (R.id.result6).....};
```

thank you for help

Comment: What does "its too long" mean? Too long for what?

Comment: i need to write a very big code cause i have 20 textview in this layout only, and i have 3 layouts.

Comment: There is no other way.  You might look into using a ListView instead of multiple textviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you started is correct, now think about putting that repetitive code in a cycle.

For example design a method that will take as the input an array of your TextView resources, and using a "for" cycle find that view by corresponding id.

```
private TextView[] initTextViews(int[] ids){

        TextView[] collection = new TextView[ids.length];

        for(int i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
            TextView currentTextView = (TextView)findViewById(ids[i]);
            collection[i]=currentTextView;
        }

        return collection;
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
// Your TextViews ids
int[] ids={R.id.result1, R.id.result2, R.id.result3};

// The resulting array
TextView[] textViews=initTextViews(ids);
```

Comment: I think this is the way i should do it

Comment: I have question ... how could you put R.id.result1 as an element for an integer array ??

Comment: Just change the parameter of method to accept an Integer array: initTextViews(Integer[] ids).

And then store your resources ids also in an Integer array: Integer[] ids={R.id.result1, R.id.result2, R.id.result3};

Comment: I mean here int[] ids={R.id.result1, R.id.result2, R.id.result3};

Comment: I believe now I understood your question. Because those ids, like "R.id.result1", actually are a representation of a number. Those numbers are stored in the R.java class. To convince yourself to this: put the mouse over the name of resourse, for R.id.result1, the name will be "result1", press CTRL key (you'll notice the id will become underlined), and then click on it. You'll be redirected to R.java file, an you'll see it's integer value.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a handle to parent the layout that contains the text views, you can recursively discover them with a function like this,

```
void getTextViews(View view, List<TextView> textViews) {
  if (view instanceof TextView) {
    textviews.add((TextView)view);
  else if (TextView instanceof ViewGroup) {
    getTextViews((ViewGroup)view, textViews);
  }
}
```

now call it like this,

```
ViewGroup topLayout = findViewById(...);
List<TextView> views = new ArrayList<TextView>();
getTextViews(topLayout, views);
TextView[] textViewArray = textViews.toArray(new TextView[0]);
```

this is quite a bit longer, but it has the advantage of not needing to change the code if you add, remove, or rename a textview.

IMHO, don't focus on writing less code, focus on writing clear code. the speed at which you type is rarely the limiting factor in your productivity.

Comment: Do not forget to check that textviewParent.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView

Comment: this is useful, but I have 4 parents every 5 textviews in one parent.

Comment: I think you also right, but i'm beginner to android and you're code is little advanced. so i didn't clearly understand it